# Stop saving when some fields and table data are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

On this code, it does not allow to save if any of table cell is empty, however, I want it now to save even the last table cell is null.

> How can i add here for last input of table row where type is not
>   hidden?

```
 $('#myTable tr input[value != add]:text').filter(function () {});
```

see my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/omuhxetx/)

This is my javascript code :

```
 $("#btnSave").click(function (event) {
        var flag = false;
        var emptyBoxes;
        var $rows = $('#myTable tr:not(:hidden)');
        $rows.each( function () {
            emptyBoxes = $('#myTable tr input[value != add]:text').filter(function () {
                return this.value == "";    
            });

            if (emptyBoxes.length != 0) {
                flag = true;
            }
        });
        if (flag) {
            alert("this cannot be empty");
            emptyBoxes.eq(0).focus();
        } else 
            alert("done");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
var fields = $('input[type=text]'); /* All fields */

/* This function will find empty fields */
var findEmptyFields = function() {

    var n = fields.length - 1;

    /* Go throw all inputs with type=text and if someone is empty return index of this element */
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (fields.eq(i).val() === '') {
            return i;
        }
    };

    /* Else return false that means that we didn't find any empty fields*/
    return false;


}

$("#btnSave").on('click', function() {

    var empty = findEmptyFields();
    if (empty === false) {
        alert('Done');
    }
    else {
        alert('Some field is empty');
        fields.eq(empty).focus();
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks. but i dont want to check for all empty field. Want to allow input on last table cell to accept null values

Comment: Ok, I see. then add css-class to inputs that you would like to check on empty (e.g. <input type='text' class='checks'>) and select them fields = $('input.checks');

Comment: Do you know code for last input of table row where type text or $(input not checks)?

Comment: Just add .check class for all items that you wanna check